# Given the relational schema provide queries in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi i started Database in univeristy a few weeks ago so im relatively new at this and i encountered this problem so im going to post my answerto one of them here and if possible can you tell me if my answer is correct or false and in case of false maybe help me provide the right answer?

Given the following relational schema:

**TRAINER (SSN, Name, Surname, City)**

**GYM (CodG, NameP, City, Address)**

**SPECIALTY (CodS, NameS, Description)**

**GROUP_LESSON (SSN, CodG, Date, CodS, ParticipantsNumber)**

Write the following queries in SQL language:

a. Show SSN, name and surname of every personal trainer who gave group lessons in

at least 3 different gyms located in Turin.

b. For each gym in which more than 10 Karate group lessons (NameS = "Karate") have

been conducted, show the code of the gym and, separately for each trainer, the

total number of participants to the group lessons (of any specialty) given by the

trainer in that gym.

c. For each personal trainer who gave group lessons at every gym in his city, show

name, surname and the number of specialties for which he gave lessons.

Answer to a

```
       Select SSN,Name,Surname

         From Trainer

         WHere SSN in(Select SSN

                     From GROUP_LESSON GL,Gym G

                     Where G.City ='Turin' AND G.CodG=GL.CodG

                     Group by (CodG,City)

                     Having count=3)
```

And as for b) and c) can't wrap my head around them! I realise that some work is required to be presented in these questions but i dont have any idea on how to do them!
Can you help me?

Comment: The `HAVING` clause is intended for _aggregate function_ conditions.

Comment: Group by SSN

                     Having count(SSN) >=3

Comment: @MetaData thank you! The rest is ok?

Comment: You can run the query and check for yourself . If b is two separate questions then i think you will be able to do it easily just proper use of group by is required. and for c you can have total no of gyms in Trainers city = distinct count of no of gyms he has taken classes in his own city( you can use either correlated subquery or CTE)